# Microsoft Graph API - MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI 404 error on beta/users/{id}/photo

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch users profile photo using the beta endpoint `beta/users/{id}/photo` of the Microsoft Graph API
but I get a 404 MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI error

```
  error: {
    code: 'MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI',
    message: 'REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox.'
    ...
```

The error does not make sense because I am trying to access Azure Ad profile picture which should not have anything to do with mailbox.

Would anyone know if I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-beta) you're using says the following about getting a user picture:

> **Note**: When attempting to GET a user photo, this operation first attempts to retrieve the specified photo from Microsoft 365. If the photo is not available in Microsoft 365, the API attempts to retrieve the photo from Azure Active Directory.

Historically the user profile picture was stored in the Exchange server, apparently they are now also saving the image somewhere else.

To check your issue, I've added a picture to a user that doesn't have any license. And started trying requests in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

1. Request to `v1.0/users/upn_here/photo` ❌ failed with `ResourceNotFound` -> `Resource could not be discovered.`
2. Request to `beta/users/upn_here/photo` ✔ gives me information about the image (eg. size)
3. Request to `v1.0/users/upn_here/photo/$value` ❌ failed with `ResourceNotFound` -> `Resource could not be discovered.`
4. Request to `beta/users/upn_here/photo/$value` ✔ gives me the image. (I see the picture I uploaded before).

[image]

You should check the used access token, copy the token and paste it here https://jwt.ms (Microsoft owned page to show you the data in the token).

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-beta#permissions) you'll need at least the delegated `User.Read` scope or the application scope `User.Read.All`.

Comment: @vma is it a cloud user or an on-premise user? I guess the above method doesn’t work for on-premise users.

Comment: @user3466681 could you verify that this solves the issue? Or do you have some more details for us, what kind of user it is (on-premise / Azure AD)?